# How to recover deleted images,videos pro-grammatically on android device?

Tags: android, delete-file, data-recovery

How can i recover files i.e images , videos, pdf from android device that are recently deleted from device.
I am following an app called "Recycle Master recycle bin" this app after being installed looks for any data that is deleted and shows it to the user and if user wants to delete or recover he can do that.
So how does it pro-grammatically doing it.

What i want from app that to recover files on being deleted similarly to the app mentioned but how it is taking this approach ,i do not have any clues.
I know about linux approach when device is rooted what about with out root.

Comment: Deleted means deleted.  Its gone.  There's nothing to recover.  The only thing that might work (and wouldn't be 100%) would be a root app that directly inspects the filesystem for recently freed inodes.

Comment: Actually, given that the app you mention says it can't recover files from before its downloaded-  my guess is it works by uploading your files to its server, so it can redownload them later.  Which will work, but probably violates copyright and privacy (if the user doesn't understand thats how it works).

Comment: Gabe, i think you are right because it is more understandable of getting your data being uploaded to the server thanks for the tip.

Comment: @GabeSechan but how does the app on just installation sends huge amount of data (images,videos) to server , after install you can directly try to delete something and the deleted file will be shown in app to restore.